# Отправление Bootstrap формы

Tags: php, bootstrap, sendmail

Надо сделать подписку на `mailchimp`с формы в `bootstrap`'е?
Нашел инструкцию - вроде все сделал как сказано: после подписки направляет на страницу с `php` и там выводит результат.

Надо чтобы он не переходил на ту страницу и вместо строки на подписку показывал сообщение "Спасибо" и т.д.

Пример - http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0819XS2

**Форма подписки**

```
            <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="assets/subscribe.php" method="post">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" class="button" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="SEND">
  </div>
        </form>
```

**Код подписки**

```
    <?php

// Email address verification
function isEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

if($_POST) {

    $mailchimp_api_key = '02dc034d3ba171812e22d904d5ea2291-us12'; // enter your MailChimp API Key
    // ****
    $mailchimp_list_id = 'ad35f3ad61'; // enter your MailChimp List ID
    // ****

    $subscriber_email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));

    if(!isEmail($subscriber_email)) {
        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 0;
        $array['message'] = 'Insert a valid email address!';
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    else {
        $array = array();
        $merge_vars = array();

        require_once 'MailChimp.php';

        $MailChimp = new \Drewm\MailChimp($mailchimp_api_key);
        $result = $MailChimp->call('lists/subscribe', array(
                'id'                => $mailchimp_list_id,
                'email'             => array('email' => $subscriber_email),
                'merge_vars'        => $merge_vars,
                'double_optin'      => true,
                'update_existing'   => true,
                'replace_interests' => false,
                'send_welcome'      => false,
        ));

        if($result == false) {
            $array['valid'] = 0;
            $array['message'] = 'An error occurred! Please try again later.';
        }
        else {
            $array['valid'] = 1;
            $array['message'] = 'Thanks for your subscription! We sent you a confirmation email.';
        }

            echo json_encode($array);

    }

}

?>
```

**Код JS**

```
$('.subscribe form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var postdata = $('.subscribe form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'assets/subscribe.php',
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.valid == 0) {
                $('.success-message').hide();
                $('.error-message').hide();
                $('.error-message').html(json.message);
                $('.error-message').fadeIn('fast', function(){
                    $('.subscribe form').addClass('animated shake').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('animated shake');
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                $('.error-message').hide();
                $('.success-message').hide();
                $('.subscribe form').hide();
                $('.success-message').html(json.message);
                $('.success-message').fadeIn('fast', function(){
                    $('.top-content').backstretch("resize");
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="assets/subscribe.php" method="post">
```

на

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" onSubmit="return false;" method="post">
```

Таким образом форма будет выполняться только с Вашего `JS` кода.
А в нем у Вас уже прописано все необходимое для отображения сообщения "Спасибо"